# Accessing "location_post" data with FQL and "distance_meters"

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get all post_ids for stories published near a certain geo point.

While reading through the Facebook FQL documentation I came across this example:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/

```
SELECT ... FROM location_post WHERE latitude = ... AND longitude = ... AND distance_meters = ...
```

When I actually try to run my query, I get

```
message": "(#602) distance_meters is not a member of the location_post table."
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FB documentation is inaccurate here (again...). There's actually a bug report for this: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/629578257122514/

You can use the following query schema:

```
select author_uid, id from location_post where distance(latitude, longitude, '52.516412', '13.377681') < 1000
```

This will give you all posts from you or your friends sent from within 1000m around the Brandenburger Tor in Berlin...